# WPF control embedded in Outlook miss backspace and space keypresses

Tags: c#, winapi, outlook, vsto

I am embedding WPF control into Outlook reading pane using this example:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a

but in C#.

Window styles I use

```
    _hwndSource = new HwndSource(0,
        (int) (WindowStyles.WS_CHILD | WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE | WindowStyles.WS_TABSTOP | 
               WindowStyles.WS_CLIPCHILDREN),
        (int)WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, 
        0, 0,
        TopPaneWindowClass, hWndParent);

    View.Loaded += _view_Loaded;
    _hwndSource.RootVisual = View;
    _hwndSource.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height;
```

It works good, except textboxes inside my control miss some keys (SPACE and BACKSPACE) - they are translated to outlook mail list instead (on SPACE it goes to the next item).
I have tried to add hook to HwndSource and process WM_GETDLGCODE:

```
_hwndSource.AddHook(ChildHwndSourceHook);
```

But it does not receive this message. It receives WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages. But how can I properly pass it to my WPF control?
Also, I can see WM_SETFOCUS, WM_GETOBJECT, WM_NCHITTEST, WM_SETCURSOR and some messages with code C131.

Edit: This is VSTO add-in (inprocess), so WPF control working in the same thread with Outlook.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the link, but I work from add-in - so this is same process and thread.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook `(SetWindowsHookExW(WH_GETMESSAGE, ...)`) and forward the `VK_TAB/VK_SPACE/VK_LEFT/VK_RIGHT`  messages to your control using `TranslateMessage`/`SendMessage`

Comment: You mean resend those messages to the exact control that has keyboard focus? Because I receive them on my WPF usercontrol that I host in HwndSource. BTW, can you also name any other issues we can expect injecting pane in Outlook this way? Did you do such things? I know you are big Outlook expert. :)

Comment: I mean, if I use AddHook to hook HwndSource that hosts my control, I can see those messages, but WPF control does not receive them. Or you suggest to use global keyboard hook?

Comment: You don't need a keyboard hook. WH_GETMESSAGE would work. When you process the incoming messages, check the control handle (HWND) to see if it is your control, and if it is, use TranslateMessage/SendMessage to directly send the message to your control. Otherwise Outlook will eat them.